# Setting up Dual Boot with Cloned Image of Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I'm not new to Linux and Ubuntu, but I  am definitely a novice. I do pretty good by following instructions I find on the internet.

I have an old Asus X75a laptop that I am replacing the hard drive in going from 1TB to 2TB. I thought what a great time to set up a dual boot machine!

But it is not quite working. What I tried was using Acronis I cloned my old drive to my new drive. Then I resized my partitions to make a partition for Ubuntu. I also made a small partition and formatted it as swap. Then I installed Ubuntu to the new partition that I made for it, formatted as ext4 mount /. That all installs quite nicely but then I never see an option to boot into Ubuntu, we go straight to Windows. (At least that works!)

Searching the internet it seems that maybe my problem is UEFI? And that dual booting isn't possible. I feel like I am 80% there though and just missing something and can pull this off. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

-AJ

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: OK I will try to do that. Unfortunately I reformatted my drive before I saw this. I will re-re-install Ubuntu how I had it and then run this script. Will be back in a day. Thanks!

Comment: Finished earlier than expected. Hoping I did this right.
[link]http://paste.ubuntu.com/15332775/[/link]

Comment: Your link is broken, but I could copy it and see it. You have BIOS boot grub installed to a partition and no UEFI boot versions of either Windows nor grub. And Windows shows no bootmgr(BIOS) nor (bootfgw.efi(UEFI) boot files nor BCD. Was Windows really BIOS boot on MBR(msdos) partitioned drive? Windows only boots from gpt with UEFI, or only in BIOS mode from MBR.

Comment: Oldfred, I installed Windows 7 clean several years ago. I know I boot fine into Windows. In the boot setup Windows Boot Manager is set to boot the machine into windows.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your firmware settings for anything referring to the Compatibility Support Module (CSM) or "legacy boot support" and *disable* any such option you find. (A few EFIs phrase these differently; they refer to "UEFI boot support" or something similar, which must then be *enabled.*) It's clear that you're booting your Ubuntu installation and repair media in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, but Windows is installed in EFI/UEFI mode. It's this discrepancy that's causing your problem.

Second, you must install an *EFI-mode* boot loader for Linux. There are two relatively easy ways to do this and many more harder ways. The two easier ways are:

- **Boot Repair** -- This program will re-install GRUB; however, you *must* boot an Ubuntu repair disc *in EFI mode* for this to work. If you can't boot your Ubuntu install/repair disc after disabling your CSM, that means it wasn't prepared correctly; see [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html#creating-media) for more on that topic. Note also that, although Boot Repair *usually* works, sometimes it doesn't, and on rare occasions it will render the computer unbootable, so you should be prepared for that possibility.
- **rEFInd** -- This program, which I maintain, is an alternative to GRUB, but with some important differences. You can download a USB flash drive or CD-R image with rEFInd from [its downloads page,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare a boot medium with it, and boot it. This should then let you boot both Windows and Ubuntu. If both options work, install the PPA or Debian package in Ubuntu. rEFInd will then take over as the default boot manager and everything should work.

Comment: Thanks.  In my boot options I have a line that says:
LAUNCH CSM [ENABLED]
and a line under it that says
LAUNCH PXE OpROM [ENABLED]

I changed both to disabled and the machine will not boot to Windows. Error message says I need to insert my Windows 7 installation disc and repair.

I can boot to my Ubuntu Live USB fine.

I might not understand, are both my Windows boot manager and my Linux boot manager wrong? If I use rEFInd will it fix both?

Comment: Regarding the Boot Repair option. With the above CSM option off, I cannot boot into Windows but to boot into my Ubuntu Live USB drive I select UEFI: PNY 2.0 FD 1100 which is my USB drive. Is this what you mean by "you must boot an Ubuntu repair disc in EFI mode for this to work. " ?

Comment: I feel like I am SO close! Thank you! I got scared of the potential to not boot at all so I skipped Boot Repair. I burned a bootable CDR of rEFInd and I can boot into Linux or Windows from the disk! Now I just have to figure out to make that permanent.

Comment: It's odd that disabling the CSM should render Windows unbootable, since there is no BIOS-mode boot loader on your hard disk. My guess is that disabling it has subtly altered the boot rules in EFI mode. In any event, since rEFInd on a USB drive works, I recommend you go ahead and install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package in Ubuntu. This *should* get everything working correctly.

Comment: Wellll...... It kind of works. I can't boot to Windows with CSM disabled. I can boot to my Ubuntu installation with CSM enabled or disabled but only if I boot from the rEFInd CD first, and then select boot from hard drive. I can't boot from the hard drive. And there is no choice at boot up for Windows or Ubuntu. So even closer.

Comment: Does this shed any more light:
[link]http://paste.ubuntu.com/15341765/

Comment: I used Magic Jelly Bean to pull my key code off of my computer, then I downloaded a Windows 7 image and burned it to a disc. Turned off and set the boot boot option to turn CSM off. Then attempted to reboot. I got the error when trying to start Windows to insert the install disc and run the repair tool. I tried but with CSM turned off I can't boot from the Windows install disc. Went back and turned CSM back on and was able to boot from the Install disc. I ran "bootrec /fixmbr" and "bootrec /fixboot" Then I rebooted. Booted into Windows fine but no Ubuntu option.

Comment: Shut down, went back into boot options and set CSM to disabled. Tried to reboot but like before won't boot into Windows with CSM off. And I can only boot into Ubuntu the rEFInd CD in drive.

Comment: Try this: First, back up the ESP (`/boot/efi` in Ubuntu). Then, after booting Ubuntu via rEFInd, type `sudo mvrefind /boot/efi/EFI/refind /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT`. This will copy rEFInd from its normal location to the fallback boot loader position, and copy what's there now (the Windows boot loader) to a backup location. My hypothesis is that your firmware is defective and is "forgetting" EFI boot manager entries. This procedure bypasses this problem by renaming rEFInd to use the fallback filename, which is used in such cases. It could go wrong, though, hence the backup at the start.

Comment: I got this error.   
//boot/efi doesn't seem to be on a VFAT filesystem. The ESP must be
mounted at //boot or //boot/efi and it must be VFAT! Aborting!  
This must be an important clue! But I don't know what it means.

Comment: It means that your ESP isn't mounted. Type this: `sudo mkdir -p /boot/efi`, followed by this: `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /boot/efi`. You should then be able to use `mvrefind`.

Comment: I still get the same error. When I started the Ubuntu install I had 3 partitions, first reserved for MS(sda1), 2nd was where windows was located(sda3), 3rd was data (sda4). I used GPart to carve out a partition for Ubuntu(sda4). I made a sliver for Swap (sda5). Then I got an error that I needed a boot partition, so I made one (sda7). The boot partition is sda2, I think, but I don't know where that came from. To make sda7 I chose "reserved for BIOS" In GPart it is labeled as file system ext4. Is this a problem?

Comment: Does this help?  [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/x352qsp5utngw6i/Screenshot%20from%202016-03-10%2017-38-12.png?dl=0

Comment: Your `/dev/sda2` is clearly your ESP. Once that's mounted at `/boot/efi`, the `mvrefind` script should be able to move it. The `mount` command I specified should mount it, but the error you're getting indicates that it's *not* mounted.  This discrepancy is probably caused by some simple basic issue with mounting the partition, so I recommend you go looking for a basic tutorial on partitions and mount points. (I have no specific references at hand, though.)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to punt. I went into the Boot Set up and selected the reset to defaults option. That locked everything up. I kept getting some kind of invalid signature error. And it didn't matter what kind of combination of CSM/Secure boot settings I did. Nothing worked. So I formatted the whole drive, downloaded a Windows 10 .iso and installed that and then Ubuntu 15.10 next to it. It took me about 4 attempts to get the partitioning right and I still have way too big of a partition necessary for SWAP. But everything works. I reloaded all of my previously backed up files and I can access them all from Linux or Windows. Thanks again for all the help. I learned a lot along the way.